# Should a woman keep her head cover while performing Wudu?

Tags: women, wudu, hijab

My mother has a question.  She was asking that can a woman perform Wudu without the Hijab (or without covering her head) and when she is done with Wudu she can cover her head.

She do Wudu alone by the way!

Is this permissible?

Comment: If a woman performs wudhu in an environment where she cannot be seen by non-mahram men, of course she does it without wearing hijab.

Comment: If you can share a reference that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make something clear:
A woman should hide more than her head or hair from the view of non-mahrams. So if a woman thinks she can make wudu' (ablution) in front of non-mahrams, but can't take of her hijab, that's a wrong thinking as to make wudu' she also would need to show her forearms (which are 'awrah too) etc. So women are asked to try their best to perform wudu' in a place non-mahrams can't see them.

Now back to your question:
Basically she could wipe over head cover under some conditons like if it is too cold. Else wudu' wouldn't be done correctly.

So taking off the hijab is rather necessary to make a correct and valid wudu'. As Allah ordered to wipe over our heads (inculding the hair) -not on the head covers- in the verse ordering and explaining wudu' (5:6):

> O you who have believed, when you rise to [perform] prayer, wash your **faces** and your **forearms to the elbows** and wipe over your **heads** and wash your **feet to the ankles**. . ..

I will try to elaborate this answer to cover the views of the different madhabs as the hanbali school seems to disagree.

See also this fatwa on [islamqa #72391](https://islamqa.info/en/72391).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... What if there are no non-mehram presented at the moment she is performing wudu? Means she is all alone while doing wudu, so then she can remove her hijab?

Comment: @Omer only in case of necissity she can wipe over the hijab. Else she can only do proper wudu' if she removed it.

Comment: @Medi1Saif That explanations needs an answer to: is "non-mahrams will see my awrah if I remove it, and I will miss prayer time if I don't do wudhu now" a case of necessity?

Answer (score -5):

I've heard that if a woman performs wudhu without hijab,all her prayers(that is her lifetime sins) will go in vain
however,i don't know about gair mehrams being present or not